# How to schedule multiple tasks on AWS ECS using different env vars?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Let's say I have task definition on AWS ECS and want to schedule it to run as multiple instances with different env variables (~20 parallel tasks). I have some ideas how to do that, but not sure which one is correct.

1. Create multiple task definitions with different env variables, which sounds not really effective and silly
2. Create multiple targets for scheduled tasks, but its number is limited to 5 ones, which doesn't work for me.
3. Create 20 container overrides, but I didn't found a way how to do it using the user interface, and not sure it's correct too.

Could you please give me an idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html) ?

Comment: Container overrides is the way I would do this.

Comment: @amitd, yes, but I need to create 20 scheduled tasks based on one task. I think creating each separate task manually isn't effective, so there should be some way to authomate it

Comment: @MarkB thanks! it's impossible using user interface, right?

Comment: When creating a scheduled task through the ECS console (the old ECS console, not the new beta version) there is a section for specifying container overrides at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @nika are you using a CI/CD service?

Comment: @MeirGabay no, I don't